# How to convert alphabet in date in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have columns with year and month in alphabet in power BI. I want to convert this to date and connect the table with the date table.

[image]

When I convert the column to date by clicking on the "ABC" symbol next to the year then all the data is converted as 01/01/2020. I want to use the months in the period column and the day of the month can be any value. So, the second row should be 02/01/2020.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom column under `Edit Queries > Add Column > Custom Column` to create your date:

[image]

[image]